# selecting data by criteria in Xarray

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have a dataset. I only want to select data that is 26˚C and higher. Ive tried everything but the problem is, when using .sel() you need temperature as a dictionary name or a coord. but in this case temperature is a grided dataset with time, depth, lat, lon as coords.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtUOY.png)
I tried this:
`t26=t.sel(t[:,:,:,:]=>26, method = 'nearest')`

and this is the error I got:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 0):

You can use xarray's `.where()` [function](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html):

```
nx = 10
da = xr.DataArray(np.random.normal(size=nx), coords=dict(x=range(nx)))
print(da)

> <xarray.DataArray (x: 10)>
> array([-0.7364476 , -0.86791627,-1.24571599, -1.34536632,  1.15486391,
>         1.39361739,  1.07317016, -1.36744902,  1.12855309, -0.90550148])
> Coordinates:   * x        (x) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

print(da.where(da > 0, drop=True))

> <xarray.DataArray (x: 4)> array([1.15486391, 1.39361739, 1.07317016,
> 1.12855309]) Coordinates:   * x        (x) int64 4 5 6 8
```